# Sort nested documents by array.prop1 and then find documents by array.0.prop2 in MongoDB/Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here are the `documents`:

```
[
  {
    "reports" : [
      {
        "date" : ISODate("2015-05-18T18:30:00.000Z"),
        "creator" : ObjectId("55ce1372f260b80927aade84"),
        "title" : "Vestibulum pulvinar leo ut risus eleifend elit"
      }, {
        "date" : ISODate("2015-05-15T18:30:00.000Z"),
        "creator" : ObjectId("55ce136af260b80927aade83"),
        "title" : "Nunc sit amet nisl ut dolor lobortis varius ut vestibulum felis"
      }
    ]
  }, {
    "reports" : [
      {
        "date" : ISODate("2015-06-23T01:00:00.000Z"),
        "creator" : ObjectId("55ce136af260b80927aade83"),
        "title" : "Nam eget diam eu nibh placerat"
      }, {
        "date" : ISODate("2015-06-07T01:00:00.000Z"),
        "creator" : ObjectId("55ce1372f260b80927aade84"),
        "title" : "Proin auctor non justo eget porta"
      }, {
        "date" : ISODate("2015-06-10T01:00:00.000Z"),
        "creator" : ObjectId("55ce1372f260b80927aade84"),
        "title" : "Curabitur pellentesque neque felis"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

For every query, I cannot sure the order of reports in `document.reports`, therefore, I want to sort it by `reports.date` in each `document` first, and then find the `documents` by `{reports.0.creator : ObjectId("55ce1372f260b80927aade84")`

Or another way,

Find `documents` by `reports.creator` where `reports.date` is the minimum/maximum.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple way if you want to `Find documents by reports.creator where reports.date is the minimum`, first `$unwind` `reports` and then match `creator`, sort this by ascending order and select document by applying limit 1.

To get maximum just reverse sort parameter to descending.

Here is a query:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $unwind: "$reports"
}, {
    $match: {
    "reports.creator": ObjectId("55ce1372f260b80927aade84")
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
    "reports.date": 1
    }
}, {
    $limit: 1
})
```

Equivalent node.js code will be something like following :

```
collection.aggregate([{
    $unwind: "$reports"
}, {
    $match: {
    "reports.creator": ObjectId("55ce1372f260b80927aade84")
    }
}, {
    $sort: {
    "reports.date": 1
    }
}, {
    $limit: 1
}], function(err, result) {
    console.log(result);
    db.close();
});
```

Comment: It works when I am trying to query with one condition, but can I `$unwind` more than one nested schemas? Let's say my documents contain `reports` and `files`. I want to find `documents` by `reports.creator` where `reports.date` is minimum and `files.src` where `files.uploadedAt` is maximum.

Comment: @kitz17  you can $unwind multiple arrays like `{$unwind:"$reports"}, {$unwind:"$files"}`